# How to retrieve/download a file stored in a BLOB in a MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The other day I recently wrote a program that takes a file that a user provided and inserts the actual file(driver) into a MySQL database BLOB.  I did the insertion as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Drivers (driver, filename, status, version, environments) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('$driver'), '$filename', $statusid, $driver_version, '$environments')";
```

As you can see above, the 'driver' field is the BLOB.  I have the filename as well in a different field.  So the question is, how can I easily get the BLOB and put it back into an actual file?  I need to get this into a file so that I can upload it to a server via SCP.  I've seen a few examples out there with content headers and such and they all look too complicated.  It was easy to load with LOAD_FILE() and I didn't know if there was another simple option to get it back to an actual file?  Sorry I don't have any code examples.  I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Step 1: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php Step 2: Don't put files inside databases. Step 3: Files in the filesystem, file location in the database.

Comment: I agree that storing them on the filesystem is probably the better solution.  However, what is the point of a BLOB or LOB then?   I'm not using PDO.

Comment: The point was to allow the storage of these types of things in the database. In theory it is a workable idea, but in practice it is typically impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql table should have at least two extra fields:

```
`mime_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

where:

- mime_type is `mime_content_type($path)` and
- size is the file's size
  in bytes, `filesize($path)`

and PHP code should look like:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: {$file['mime_type']}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: {$file['size']}");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename= {$file['filename']}");

return $file['driver'];
```

The reasons for storing data as binary in SQL are dictated by business rules. For example, I store contracts that have to remain private.